# How to get doubles from text c++

Tags: c++, input

I have a text document which looks something like this:

```
user_name1 1.575
user_name2 3.636
user_name3 2.647
user_name4 5.532
user_name5 4.253
```

What i am trying to do is, to get these numbers from .txt file into console and save them as variables. I know how to read .txt file in console and I found some answers here how to get each line separately as strings, but i can't get these doubles. Is there some kind of function or whatsoever that goes through strings and finds numbers?

I tried with this:

1) get string of each line
2) loop through them and check ASCII code and if it is a number I saved next 3 or 4 charachters

But its not working very well. Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
string line;

ifstream banka ("banka.txt");

double numbers[5];
if(banka.is_open()) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        getline(cin,line);
        size_t space=line.find(' ');
        string numStr=line.substr(space+1);
        double num = stod(numStr);
        numbers[i]=num;

    }
    banka.close();
}
else {
    cout<<"Unable to open file."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you have a supporting compiler, you can use `std::regex`

Comment: Have you looked at `fscanf()`?

Comment: Show us the code that is "not working well". otherwise we can't identify what your problem is.

Comment: [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: Ugh, worse and worse advices... regexes, `scanf()`, ... NO! `getline()`, `std::string::find()` and `std::stod()`.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit I am using xcode.

Comment: @spafrou Xcode is not a compiler.

Comment: +1 for `std::stod()`
I was not aware of that addition.

Comment: @JonathanWood Not yet i will look it up. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
std::string ln; // line
while (std::getline(std::cin, ln)) {
    std::size_t space = ln.find(' ');
    std::string nameStr = ln.substr(0, space);
    std::string numStr = ln.substr(space + 1);
    double num = std::stod(numStr);
}
```

Comment: I'll try this one out :)

Comment: I tried this code and used cout to check in console, but it's not working though i think i am doing something wrong. And one more thing: I always have 5 lines, so that means 5 double numbers. Can I simply use for loop instead of while and save those doubles into an array? Thank you for your help

Comment: @spafrou It **is** working. Yes, you can use a for loop. Note: don't use the currently top rated (albeit not too good) answer, it's dangerous.

Comment: can you look up my edited code? It gives me an error:
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stod: no conversion

Comment: @spafrou then you are passing it a string that does not represent a number. since you haven't shown the format of your file, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I have a "banka.txt" file and it looks exactly like described in my question. I changed only names

Comment: Wow i did it now. Thank you very much for your help. Marked as answered.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply this ?

```
std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
std::string str;
double num;

while (fin >> str >> num)
{

    std::cout << str << " :" << num <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: because it's not reliable.

Comment: @H2CO3 I won't argue with [these](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1870232/p0w) people, but exactly why its not reliable ? I think it is as long as they are as separated by white space

Comment: because `operator>>` is subject to `iomanip` stream manipulators and other "funny" stuff, so you can never be sure that it does what's advertised. Basically, this operator has the very same problem as `scanf()`: it tries to do two things at once (getting user input and parsing it), and - not surprisingly - it fails to do its job properly, similar to its C counterpart.

Comment: @H2CO3 How does `scanf()` fail to do its job? I know it isn't type-safe, but that isn't a parallel in this situation.

Comment: @P0W:  Aww, I haven't made the list. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's messy, its usage is counter-intuitive and it's prone to UB (although the last assertion does not apply to `operator>>`).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the line contains one space and only one space:

```
string dstr = line.substr(line.find(' ')+1);
double d = strtod(dstr.c_str(), NULL);
```

Comment: i have a number: 1.34 and this gives me 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::istringstream to parse a string:

```
std::istringstream iss("user_name1 1.575");
std::string str;
double d;
iss >> str >> d;
```